# relaunch a function with each update of specific states react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I created a function (newdispo) in componant didmount
to create reservation availability feed,
it is based on relative day's date
from 10:00 to 19:00 (for exemple)
it will create availability with intervals with the state (intervals)
(1 hour for example)
so it shows me the availability relative to today's date 'this.stat.day'
today (07/04/2020)
example:
04/07/2020 - 10:00
04/07/2020 - 11:00 ect ...

however I would like to make the page flexible,
I have a nav bar with the next day of the week, when I click on another day,
the state 'day' if updates with the selected day,

I would like the function (newdispo) to be restarted each time the state is updated
and that the feed change is updated every time I change the state 'interval' or 'days'

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

     day :'07/04/2020',
     interval : '00:60:00',
     dispo: []

  }

 }



  componentDidMount(day,interval,newdispo){

    interval:this.state.interval
    day:this.state.day
    newdispo = [{ date:day
                  hour: ...},
                { date:day
                  hour: ...} ect..]

    this.setState=({ dispo: newdispo});
   }

   changeday = (e) => {

      this.setState=({ day:e.target})

      }

   changeinterval = (e) => {

      this.setState=({ interval : e.target })

      }


  render(){

  return (

   <button onclick={this.changeday}>08/04/2020</button>
   <button onclick={this.changeday}>09/04/2020</button>
   //ect..//

   < button onclick={this.changeinterval}>00:30:00</button>
     < button onclick={this.changeinterval}>02:00:00</button>
     //ect..//

    this.state.calendar.map((time) => {

     <button value:{time.date} >{ time.hour} </button>

     })}

   )

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle method [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is the one you need, e.g.:

```
componentDidUpdate( prevProps, prevState ) {

    if( this.state.day !== prevState.day ){
        this.setState=({
            dispo: [
                { date: ..., hour: ...},
                ...
            ]
        });
    }
}
```